# Install prospector with pipenv fails due to astroid version conflict

Tags: python-3.x, pipenv

I'm trying to install prospector with pipenv. But the installation fails due to the version conflict in astroid. Astroid is a sub-dependency for prospector. This failure started since the astroid 2.0 release on 15th July 2018. Before that, the build didn't complain and was successful

Pipfile

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]

Flask = "*"

[dev-packages]
prospector = "*"
```

Log for pipenv install --dev

```
Pipfile.lock not found, creating...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...

Warning: Your dependencies could not be resolved. You likely have a mismatch in your sub-dependencies.
  You can use $ pipenv install --skip-lock to bypass this mechanism, then run $ pipenv graph to inspect the situation.
  Hint: try $ pipenv lock --pre if it is a pre-release dependency.
Could not find a version that matches astroid<2.0,>=1.4,>=1.6,>=2.0.0
Tried: 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0, 1.3.0, 1.3.1, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.3.7, 1.3.8, 1.3.8, 1.4.0, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.9, 1.5.0, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.3, 1.6.0, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.5, 2.0, 2.0
Skipped pre-versions: 2.0.0.dev0, 2.0.0.dev0, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev1, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0.dev2, 2.0.0.dev3, 2.0.0.dev3, 2.0.0.dev4, 2.0.0.dev4
There are incompatible versions in the resolved dependencies.
```

In the above warning, there is a conflicting version restriction. <2.0,>=2.0.0. But when I checked the pipenv graph, none of the dependencies have >=2.0.0 restriction for astroid

pipenv graph

```
flask-restplus==0.11.0
  - aniso8601 [required: >=0.82, installed: 3.0.2]
  - Flask [required: >=0.8, installed: 1.0.2]
    - click [required: >=5.1, installed: 6.7]
    - itsdangerous [required: >=0.24, installed: 0.24]
    - Jinja2 [required: >=2.10, installed: 2.10]
      - MarkupSafe [required: >=0.23, installed: 1.0]
    - Werkzeug [required: >=0.14, installed: 0.14.1]
  - jsonschema [required: Any, installed: 2.6.0]
  - pytz [required: Any, installed: 2018.5]
  - six [required: >=1.3.0, installed: 1.11.0]
gevent==1.3.5
  - greenlet [required: >=0.4.13, installed: 0.4.14]
prospector==0.12.11
  - dodgy [required: >=0.1.9, installed: 0.1.9]
  - mccabe [required: >=0.5.0, installed: 0.6.1]
  - pep8-naming [required: >=0.3.3, installed: 0.7.0]
    - flake8-polyfill [required: >=1.0.2,<2, installed: 1.0.2]
      - flake8 [required: Any, installed: 3.5.0]
        - mccabe [required: >=0.6.0,<0.7.0, installed: 0.6.1]
        - pycodestyle [required: >=2.0.0,<2.4.0, installed: 2.3.1]
        - pyflakes [required: >=1.5.0,<1.7.0, installed: 1.6.0]
  - pycodestyle [required: >=2.0.0,<2.4.0, installed: 2.3.1]
  - pydocstyle [required: >=2.0.0, installed: 2.1.1]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
    - snowballstemmer [required: Any, installed: 1.2.1]
  - pyflakes [required: >=0.8.1,<2.0.0, installed: 1.6.0]
  - pylint [required: >=1.5.6,<2.0.0, installed: 1.9.2]
    - astroid [required: >=1.6,<2.0, installed: 1.6.5]
      - lazy-object-proxy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.1]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
      - wrapt [required: Any, installed: 1.10.11]
    - isort [required: >=4.2.5, installed: 4.3.4]
    - mccabe [required: Any, installed: 0.6.1]
    - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
  - pylint-common [required: >=0.2.5, installed: 0.2.5]
    - pylint [required: >=1.0, installed: 1.9.2]
      - astroid [required: >=1.6,<2.0, installed: 1.6.5]
        - lazy-object-proxy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.1]
        - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
        - wrapt [required: Any, installed: 1.10.11]
      - isort [required: >=4.2.5, installed: 4.3.4]
      - mccabe [required: Any, installed: 0.6.1]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
    - pylint-plugin-utils [required: >=0.2.5, installed: 0.4]
      - pylint [required: Any, installed: 1.9.2]
        - astroid [required: >=1.6,<2.0, installed: 1.6.5]
          - lazy-object-proxy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.1]
          - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
          - wrapt [required: Any, installed: 1.10.11]
        - isort [required: >=4.2.5, installed: 4.3.4]
        - mccabe [required: Any, installed: 0.6.1]
        - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
  - pylint-plugin-utils [required: >=0.2.6, installed: 0.4]
    - pylint [required: Any, installed: 1.9.2]
      - astroid [required: >=1.6,<2.0, installed: 1.6.5]
        - lazy-object-proxy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.1]
        - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
        - wrapt [required: Any, installed: 1.10.11]
      - isort [required: >=4.2.5, installed: 4.3.4]
      - mccabe [required: Any, installed: 0.6.1]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
  - pyyaml [required: Any, installed: 3.13]
  - requirements-detector [required: >=0.4.1, installed: 0.5.2]
    - astroid [required: >=1.4, installed: 1.6.5]
      - lazy-object-proxy [required: Any, installed: 1.3.1]
      - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
      - wrapt [required: Any, installed: 1.10.11]
  - setoptconf [required: >=0.2.0, installed: 0.2.0]
```

Appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question :)

Was able to figure out the issue with below methods.

Even though the "pipenv graph" doesn't mention any dependency which restricts astroid >=2.0.0, if I do the "pipenv lock --verbose" it clearly shows that pylint-plugin-utils version 0.4 expects astroid to be >=2.0.0

According to my packages, pylint-plugin-utils should be >=0.2.6. Therefore I added the sub dependencies in the piffle as below

```
[dev-packages]
astroid = "==1.6.5"
pylint-plugin-utils = "==0.2.6"
prospector = "*"
```

I specifically mentioned the astroid version since if not it installs version 2.0 and some other sub packages expects it to be <2.0